# Is it safe to assume an Integer will always be 32 bits in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, integer, alias, int32

> Related:
>
> [Is it safe to assume an int will
>   always be 32 bits in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164643/is-it-safe-to-assume-an-int-will-always-be-32-bits-in-c)

The linked question asks whether it is "safe to assume that an int will always be 32 bits in C#".  The accepted answer states that "the C# specification rigidly defines that int is an alias for System.Int32 with exactly 32 bits".

My question is this: does this hold true for VB.Net's Integer?  Is it safe to assume that Integer will always be an alias for int32?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.
The `Integer` type will never change.

The [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711900%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (7.3 Primitive Types) says:

> The integral value types Byte (1-byte unsigned integer), Short (2-byte signed integer), Integer (4-byte signed integer), and Long (8-byte signed integer). These types map to System.Byte, System.Int16, System.Int32, and System.Int64, respectively. The default value of an integral type is equivalent to the literal 0.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  For reference, it's in section 7.3 of the VB.Net 2008 (.NET 3.5/VB 9) spec as well.

Comment: AFAIK, the newer specs aren't deep-linkable online (they're only available as Word documents)

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net doesn't have an "int", it has an "Integer" type.  The Integer type is an alias for System.Int32.  So no, this will not change.