# What is the difference between double.Parse and Double.Parse?

Tags: c#, parsing

What is the difference between `double.Parse(myString)` and `Double.Parse(myString)`? Is there a difference in performance or reasons I should use one but not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` is just a language alias for `System.Double` (a class recognized by the CLR), so it should be exactly the same.

Are you experiencing a specific problem that would indicate otherwise?

Comment: I want to clear up my understanding from the long comments, so: 'double' is a keyword (or alias) for System.Double, and my question should be, more correctly, "difference between double and System.Double". Am I right?

Comment: Your question is correct (at least the way those of us on planet earth understand it) and the answers you've received (save Ali's response) answer it correctly. In short, `double` is just something that ends up meaning `System.Double` to the compiler. They are the same thing it's just that the compiler lets you use `double` for legacy compatibility.

Comment: @KMC: M.Babcock says it so well I don't need to add anything to that.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct, so I removed the weasel-words. :-)

Answer (score 2):

None-what-so-ever...
double is an alias for System.Double. Nothing else.

so double.Parse is exactly the same as Double.Parse.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing; One of them (`double` or `Double` - don't remember) is an alias for the other.

The compiler takes care of it, so there's literally no difference.

There are other pairs of examples of this, too, like `int`/`Int32` and `String`/`string`

Comment: then why both exist? if two are doing same thing, one shouldn't exist?

Comment: @KMC See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626056/in-c-why-is-int-an-alias-for-system-int32

Comment: @KMC - Consider it syntactic sugar for those developers coming from a C/C++ background.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely,

> The following table shows the keywords for built-in C# types, which are
>   aliases of predefined types in the System namespace.

bool    -->           System.Boolean

decimal    -->                    System.Decimal

double    -->                     System.Double

int    -->                        System.Int32

Complete list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In Simple word, Double is just alias for double, just Press F12 on Double Word to see this. In fact main type is double, but in .net Framework it's Double See [msdn about double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).