# int vs Int32. Are they really aliases?

Tags: c#, .net, value-type

After looking at the source code for Int32 while doing some research as to why my DataContractSerializer would not serialize my struct but when using int it works fine, I came across a curious bit of code

```
public struct Int32 : ...
{
   internal int m_value;

   public const int MaxValue = 0x7fffffff;
```

If Int32 and int are aliases why on earth is int declared inside Int32?

Comment: Did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626056/in-c-why-is-int-an-alias-for-system-int32

Comment: "What is the `int` standing on?" "You're very clever, young man, very clever," said the old lady. "But it's `int`s all the way down!"

Comment: @saravanan Checked the question but not sure of the relevancy. How can int be an alias to Int32 if Int32 contains and int. Isn't there a stack overflow concern here also?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Stack overflow concerns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` vs. `Int32` is irrelevant to this issue. That the field is displayed as `int` is just because the tool you use to look at it replaces those types by their aliases when it displays them. If you look at is with a lower level tool you'll see that it doesn't know about `int`, only about `Int32`.

The problem is that the `Int32` struct contains an `Int32` field.

> "What is the `int` standing on?" "You're very clever, young man, very clever," said the old lady. "But it's `int`s all the way down!"

The solution to this problem is *magic*. The runtime knows what an `Int32` is and gives it special treatment avoiding infinite recursion. You can't write a custom struct that contains itself as a field. `Int32` is a built in type, no normal struct. It just appears as struct for consistency's sake.

Comment: As in Arthur C. Clarke's Third Law: "*Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic*".

Answer (score 0):

well its almost the same as alias
what this will do will put the int everywhere where int32 is used because MaxValue is constant it will not be created with the value.

so basically creating int32 will create one element structure with only int. but thanks to using structure MaxValue can be obtain at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not as silly as it seems, because normally it would lead to a cyclic struct layout to have an instance field inside the `struct` which had the same type as the entire struct. For example, this will not work, cleraly:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  internal MyStruct m_value;
}
```

Gives:

> error CS0523: Struct member 'SomeNamespace.MyStruct.m_value' of type
>   'SomeNamespace.MyStruct' causes a cycle in the struct layout

compile-time error. So there must be some magic for `Int32`.

Update: See thread [If Int32 is just an alias for int, how can the Int32 class use an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113850/).