# How many bytes of memory does each type in .NET consume (32-bit environment)?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

How much memory in bytes do types like `int`, `bool`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `object`, and `string` use when added as a field to an instance of a class?

Comment: that depends on several things like .NET version and bitness (32 versus 64 bits)... the exact memory layout is usually unknown before runtime! For approximate figure you can check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Yahia actually 32bit vs 64bit does not matter.
Byte will be byte, Int32 will be Int32 etc

Comment: @JohnDemetriou do you have a source to back up your claim?

Comment: @user1306322 sure, let me find it :) but I am talking c# specifically, just to be clear
as for the link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx

an Int32 explicitly means 32 bits of width, regardless of system. Calling it int is just a shorthand (or sugar-coating)

Also a Q&A from SO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164643/is-an-int-a-64-bit-integer-in-64-bit-c

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. I thought you meant they take up different amounts of ram depending on the target platform bitness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.80).aspx) shows the size of each datatype in bits (divide by 8 to get bytes):

```
byte 8
sbyte 8
int 32
uint 32
short 16
ushort 16
etc...
```

Object and string are reference types. Reference types take up at least the size of all the fields they contain plus the size of the reference itself.

**Related**

- [How big is an object reference in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800882/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-net)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that the numbers represent bits not bytes